# Piped sdt output with notification Python

Tags: python, notifications, pipe

I'm playing around with python and have written an application that generates a lot of text which it prints to the stdout.(I run the application in a console(bash) and don't want to use a GUI or external tool) 
The process takes up a lot of time and I can calculate how much it has already finished..

The output of the application is always piped from the running script..

I would like to present a notification to the user from time to time of how much of the text generation is done.. (I can't print to stdout because it is redirected to some other process..)
Is there some way to do this?

Your suggestions are much appreciated!

Comment: look at how [`pv` utility reports progress](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pv)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what `stderr` is for.

Take a look at this example program:

```
import sys
print >> sys.stderr, "Starting..."
print "Done!"
```

If you redirect its output with `>` (for example, `python test.py > test.txt`), anything printed to `stderr` will not be included.

`test.txt` will just have `Done!` in it.

Comment: From the question: I can't print to std because it is redirected to some other process.

Comment: @YevgenYampolskiy And what is `std`? That's not a stream. There's no reason to be redirecting both `stderr` and `stdout`, which are different streams.

Comment: I guess he meant `stderr`. Many applications write main output to `stdout`, and log to `stderr`. They run out of communication streams this way.

Comment: Although I don't like to use stderr for this, this will work for me.. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can generate additional file somewhere where you record status of your application. On UNIX platforms users can `tail` it in another console. Sending e-mails with status  is another option.

Comment: As I have mentioned before.. I do not want to use any outside tool so using tail to print the contents of the file is no good.. Also I would like to use the same console for the status updates where the application has started..